# Products and categories not displaying in admin

Tags: magento-2.1, product, admin-panel, tabs

I have successfully installed magento 2.1.7 but icons are not showing at admin side and i have installed magento with sample data. 
Clicking on product tab it is showing me nothing.

I am new in magento so please help.

Comment: Have you applied my answer solution?

Comment: where to put this code ? i am new so i dont know where to put this code @SHPatel.

Comment: You need to run this command from your magento setup.

Comment: @SHPatel it is working Thank yous so much :)

Comment: @SHPatel it should be php 'yourmagentofoldername'/ bin/magento setup:upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below commands form your Magento root path and check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe permission issue also. Provide necessary permissions. Navigate to `/app/bootstrap.php:11`. Uncomment the line.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

It will provide you more info. Comment out this line once you debug the issue.